# Core data with iCloud.. seems like they have two storage

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, synchronization, icloud

I made app for iOS and Mac with core data with iCloud. 
Synchronizing with any device is working great until iOS8 came out.

since iOS8 came out, in XCode and provisioning portal, I had to put one more ubiquaty key like "iCloud.xxx.xxx" with my previous one "XMKH8e3SK.xxx.xxx" at the same time. I didn't want to make any change to my app but I had to, because once Apple migrate my apps's data to iCloud drive, data is gone and it's restored when I put that key(iCloud prefix "iCloud.xxx.xx" in XCode and provisionaing portal).

It seems OK after that.

but now I have really serious problem.

MY IPAD(iOS8) ~ MY MACBOOK AIR(Yosemite) is syncing each other and MY IPHONE 6(iOS8) ~ MY IMAC(Yosemite) is syncing each othere BUT NOT ALL DEVICES!! 
It's too weird. Can not believe this is happening. I hope not my customers are facing this issue. but They are!

How can i solver this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: iCloud Drive has different storage to the original iCloud document storage. Once a user has opted-in to iCloud Drive, and their data has been migrated over, there will be no further transfer between the two storages. Ie, an iOS 7 or 10.9 device cannot sync with an iOS 8 or 10.10 device that is using iCloud Drive.

Comment: Yes. I also think it happened. but in my case, my iPad - my macbook air syncing / iPhone - my iMac syncing . all iOS devices are iOS8 and version of all OSX is Yosemite. That's why I ask question.

Comment: How do I know which storage this device is linked? How to know is it's from iCloud or iCloud drive?

Comment: I don't think there is a standard way to know if a device is using iCloud Drive. Maybe you can think up a hack. You should probably just support iCloud Drive, and tell your customers to upgrade. Also, make sure you are using the same ubiquity container id on each device.

Comment: "make sure you are using the same ubiquity container id on each device." ? Can I choose any id of it?

Comment: I set ubiquity id on XCode. I selected two. one is starting with my team ID like "Q35KEHJ.xxx.company" and second one is "iCloud.xxx.company"(for iCloud drive).

Comment: Each identity has different storage in iCloud. If you want your devices to share files, you need to use the same identity on each device, when asking for the URL of the ubiquity container. Using different identities will result in files going into different folders, and they will not be shared.

Comment: Thank Drew. I continued my question here. Could you please keep answering here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008827/core-data-with-icloud-makes-an-another-storage-sometimes-when-app-updates-or-som